# Draw bitmap over already drawn background on the SurfaceView

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

In my SurfaceView when I click on the screen it creates black dots after that I connect them and it has a filled with color. After that I am ttrying to draw other bitmap and I want the current state be something like a background and when I touch the screen I want to draw a bitmap on this possition and when I am trying to draw a bitmap on touch location the canvas goes back to the previous state with the draws.

Here is my code:

```
package com.inveitix.android.clue.ui.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import com.inveitix.android.clue.R;
import com.inveitix.android.clue.cmn.Door;
import com.inveitix.android.clue.cmn.MapPoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

    private static final String TAG = "DrawingView";
    private static final float DOOR_SIZE = 30;

    private Paint paint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private int maxHeight;
    private int maxWidth;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private List<MapPoint> shape;
    private List<Door> doors;
    private float ratio;
    private boolean isFloorFinished;
    private boolean isDoorSelected;
    Path path;

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void setIsDoorSelected(boolean isDoorSelected) {
        this.isDoorSelected = isDoorSelected;
    }

    public void setIsFloorFinished(boolean isFloorFinished) {
        this.isFloorFinished = isFloorFinished;
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        isFloorFinished = false;
        surfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        prepareCanvas();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        shape = new ArrayList<>();
        doors = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void prepareCanvas() {
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
        int minh = getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop() + getSuggestedMinimumHeight();
        this.maxWidth = resolveSizeAndState(minw, widthMeasureSpec, 1);
        this.maxHeight = resolveSizeAndState(minh, heightMeasureSpec, 1);
        if (ratio != 0) {
            maxHeight = (int) (maxWidth / ratio);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onMeasure width:" + maxWidth);
        Log.i(TAG, "onMeasure height:" + maxHeight);
        setMeasuredDimension(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !isFloorFinished) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                shape.add(new MapPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                for (MapPoint point : shape) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(point.getX(), point.getY(), 10, paint);
                }
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isDoorSelected) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                Door door = new Door();
                door.setConnectedTo("door1"); //this is for test
                door.setX(event.getX());
                door.setY(event.getY());
                doors.add(door);
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                drawDoors(canvas);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void drawFloor() {
        Bitmap bmpFloorPattern = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.floor_pattern6);
        BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(bmpFloorPattern,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        path = new Path();
        path.reset();

        if (shape != null) {
            path.moveTo(shape.get(0).getX(), shape.get(0).getY());
            alignPoints(path);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            for (int i = 0; i < shape.size(); i++) {
                path.lineTo(shape.get(i).getX(), shape.get(i).getY());
            }
        }
        paint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        paint.setShader(null);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    public void drawDoors(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bmpDoor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.door32);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        if (doors != null && doors.size() > 0) {
            for (Door door : doors) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmpDoor, door.getX() - DOOR_SIZE, door.getY() - DOOR_SIZE, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void alignPoints(Path path) {
        MapPoint previousPoint = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < shape.size(); i++) {
            float x = shape.get(i).getX();
            float y = shape.get(i).getY();
            if (previousPoint != null) {
                float deltaX = Math.abs(x - previousPoint.getX());
                float deltaY = Math.abs(y - previousPoint.getY());
                if (Math.max(deltaX, deltaY) == deltaX) {
                    x = previousPoint.getX();
                } else {
                    y = previousPoint.getY();
                }
            }
            path.lineTo(x, y);
            previousPoint = shape.get(i);
        }
    }

    public void setWidthToHeightRatio(float ratio) {
        this.ratio = ratio;
        maxHeight = (int) (maxWidth / ratio);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to draw over the drawn background ?

Comment: drawFloor() is not invoked in the code snippet. Can you show the code for your entire draw sequence?

Comment: Question updated with the full code.

Comment: Still not seeing where drawFloor() is invoked. Also, if I understand your question correctly, you are drawing a background, then drawing the touch locations, but they are not appearing- is that correct?

Comment: They apears but when they apears my background go in the old states with white background and on every 3rd touch of the screen background apears again, the touched points are correctly appear but background changes on every touch. I want to draw over the current state of the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it I have to draw doors in the same time with the floor so I did this changes:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !isFloorFinished) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                shape.add(new MapPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                for (MapPoint point : shape) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(point.getX(), point.getY(), 10, paint);
                }
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && isDoorSelected) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                Door door = new Door();
                door.setConnectedTo("door1"); //this is for test
                door.setX(event.getX());
                door.setY(event.getY());
                doors.add(door);
                drawFloor();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void drawFloor() {
        Bitmap bmpFloorPattern = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.floor_pattern6);
        BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(bmpFloorPattern,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        path = new Path();
        path.reset();

        if (shape != null) {
            path.moveTo(shape.get(0).getX(), shape.get(0).getY());
            alignPoints(path);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            for (int i = 0; i < shape.size(); i++) {
                path.lineTo(shape.get(i).getX(), shape.get(i).getY());
            }
        }
        paint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        paint.setShader(null);
        if(doors.size() > 0) {
            drawDoors();
        }
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
```